# Clock won't keep time after Mavericks installation

Tags: macos, clock, ntp

My clock no longer keeps time properly after installation of Mavericks. This problem affects all of my iMacs immediately post-Mavericks, so it's not an issue with a bad battery.

The symptom is: The clock drifts by about a minute per day. Clicking the Date & Time applet in Settings immediately syncs the clock to the correct time. So the NTP servers are obviously working. It's just that Mavericks doesn't make use of them to set the system clock unless the Date & Time applet is clicked.

I followed the advise [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/112679/ntpd-not-updating-time) and used the UI to set multiple time servers. I used the recommended string: `0.us.pool.ntp.org, 1.us.pool.ntp.org, 2.us.pool.ntp.org, 3.us.pool.ntp.org`

After having made this change, instead of the clock losing thirty seconds per day, now it gains one minute per day.

As you can see from the log, it executes a few time syncs correctly and then just stops. The last sync was executed back on 1/17/14 at 4:40pm:

```
1/17/14, 2:06:08 PM ntpd: proto precision = 1.00 usec
1/17/14, 2:06:19 PM ntpd: proto precision = 1.00 usec
1/17/14, 2:09:25 PM ntpd: proto precision = 1.00 usec
1/17/14, 2:09:30 PM ntpd: ntpd exiting on signal 15
1/17/14, 2:09:30 PM ntpd: proto precision = 1.00 usec
1/17/14, 2:09:36 PM ntpd: ntpd exiting on signal 15
1/17/14, 2:09:36 PM ntpd: proto precision = 1.00 usec
1/17/14, 2:13:34 PM ntpd: proto precision = 1.00 usec
1/17/14, 2:20:10 PM ntpd: SYNC state ignoring +0.156620 s
1/17/14, 2:37:33 PM ntpd: ntpd: time set +0.241899 s
1/17/14, 2:58:17 PM ntpd: ntpd: time set +1.052795 s
1/17/14, 3:42:36 PM ntpd: SYNC state ignoring -1.002861 s
1/17/14, 3:42:37 PM ntpd: ntpd: time set -1.012315 s
1/17/14, 4:41:31 PM ntpd: SYNC state ignoring -1.369896 s
```

Apparently the problem can be solved if the user knows Unix and can actually [recompile parts of the operating system](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23924875#23924875). This is way beyond my level of expertise. I did run ntpdate -q time.apple.com *after* clicking the UI's Date & Time control so things here haven't gotten out of sync just yet:

```
server 17.151.16.38, stratum 2, offset -1.405741, delay 0.04819
server 17.171.4.14, stratum 2, offset -1.404515, delay 0.09674
server 17.171.4.15, stratum 2, offset -1.406511, delay 0.09543
server 17.171.4.33, stratum 2, offset -1.405914, delay 0.09560
server 17.171.4.34, stratum 2, offset -1.405216, delay 0.09547
server 17.171.4.35, stratum 2, offset -1.405537, delay 0.09482
server 17.171.4.36, stratum 2, offset -1.406435, delay 0.09608
server 17.171.4.37, stratum 2, offset -1.409832, delay 0.10497
server 17.151.16.12, stratum 2, offset -1.405502, delay 0.04555
server 17.151.16.14, stratum 2, offset -1.405269, delay 0.04694
server 17.151.16.20, stratum 2, offset -1.407573, delay 0.04491
server 17.151.16.21, stratum 2, offset -1.404786, delay 0.04668
server 17.151.16.22, stratum 2, offset -1.405651, delay 0.04752
server 17.151.16.23, stratum 2, offset -1.406247, delay 0.04523
server 17.171.4.13, stratum 2, offset -1.405871, delay 0.09541
19 Jan 10:29:24 ntpdate[33548]: step time server 17.151.16.20 offset -1.407573 sec
```

**Is there a problem with this update OS to make it better able to tell time properly without having to deal with cryptic Unix commands and OS recompilations?**

Comment: You have pointed out what looks to be problems in the shift away from `ntp` and to `pacemaker` on Mavericks. Clearly some but not all people are seeing poor behavior, but if you can reproduce this - reporting the bug to Apple might be the fastest way to get Apple to fix their code. If you want to edit in how you determine your clocks are misbehaving that might help others discover they are affected and collaborate on a workaround.

Comment: Also - what does `ntpdate -q time.apple.com` show for your offset and delay values?

Comment: Hi Mike. The people experiencing the problem upgraded to Mavericks, whereas the people who aren't did a clean installation. I ran the command you provided and received: (well, looks like this site has a limit on length of what I can post... i'll try adding it to my original question)

Comment: Absolutely - edit it in the main thread. I'll do what I can to get an answer - clearly some people are finding holes in the default settings on 10.9 and 10.9.1. See this awesome answer on [steering pacemaker](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/117865/5472) to adjust time more often than the default 10 or more seconds...

Comment: Would you join us in [chat] to see if we can troubleshoot this a bit before guessing an answer?

Comment: Interesting article. It looks like the interval is already set to 1 second, tolerance=.000358, and drift=357.57. Not sure what that means but thought it might be helpful. It's odd that 'ntpd' does its thing once per hour for a few hours follow my click of the Date and Time applet, but then stops.... never to resume again.

Comment: It won't let me participate in chat. Says I must be logged in and have 20 reputation. Not sure what reputation is but I am logged in.

Comment: You have plenty of reputation to chat, but the user there is sometimes a pain to set up. You actually have to create a chat account and then link it to an account with enough rep to work.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the solution has been identified:

Here are the steps

1. Replace Mavericks' buggy usr/sbin/ntpd executable with the one from your backups or other Mac with the previous version of OS X.
2. Delete var/db/ntp.drift
3. Restart the ntpd process using the new executable

I can verify that the clock now stays in sync. It's an absolutely ridiculous solution to a simple problem but it works. Thanks Gary at the Apple forum for the solution and emailing me the new executable. Also thanks to input from bmike above.

Comment: I think recompiling sounds easier. How do i get a copy of the executable from a past osx version?