# How do I use UTC with NTP?

Tags: macos, data-synchronization, clock, ntp, time

Looking at:

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH9069

How do I set the clock to use UTC with NTP?

(This is in the context of synchronizing the Mac with the Linux server, both should be using UTC and, preferably, connect to the same NTP server.)

Comment: see also:  http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117864/how-can-i-tell-if-my-mac-is-keeping-the-clock-updated-properly?rq=1  I'm not sure whether this mac runs pacer or not.

Answer (score 2):

OSX has NTP built in, and enabled by default already.

From the Apple menu -> System Preferences -> Date and Time

Make sure that ***Set Date and Time Automatically*** is checked. That's NTP. You can pick a default Apple NTP server, or set your own, eg. pick one from here: http://www.pool.ntp.org/zone/north-america

For UTC time zone, click over to the ***Time Zone*** tab, and enter "*UTC - United Kingdom*" as the Closest City.

Comment: I had a chance to get on the mac today.  I should've included the context of the question (I'll update the question):  the linux server and apple client should use the same NTP server and both be set to UTC.  It turned out that switching Mac's (apparently) fixed it without getting into NTP, so..It's probably easier to set the Linux server to use `time.apple.com` than futz with the mac?

Comment: I'd recommend using a NTP pool machine on both. Might be worth reading this article, if you're concerned with high accuracy between machines: http://www.atmythoughts.com/living-in-a-tech-family-blog/2014/2/28/what-time-is-it

Comment: Very few references online to "UTC - United Kingdom" as a location, but we've just encountered it with some Macs deciding that's where they're located (rather than, say, London)!