# The `ntpdate` command was removed from Mojave. What to use now?

Tags: macos, command-line, ntp, mojave

In the latest macOS version (Mojave 10.14 Beta) the `ntpdate` tool has been removed. What I want to do is to simply restart the computer clock using an NTP server:

```
sudo ntpdate -u pool.ntp.org
```

Has Apple published the reasoning behind the removal, and have they replaced it with something else?

Comment: For whether they've replaced it with something else, it seems they were already phasing it out in previous macOS versions, see [How can I tell if my Mac is keeping the clock updated properly?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/117864/37797)

Comment: I would say this question, is different from the duplicate.

The current question is asking for a command alternative, while the linked question is asking how to tell if time is updating. 

It is possible to use `sudo sntp -sS hostname` as an alternative to `sudo ntpdate -u hostname`.

[Source](https://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Dev/DeprecatingNtpdate#Run_once_set_the_time_ASAP)