# Date is wrong by months when set to automatically

Tags: macos, time, ntp

Since a few days my MacBook Air 2020 shows the wrong date when set to "Set date and time automatically".
This is regardless of the chosen NTP server.

When time set manually, querying a NTP server from the command line returns:

```
$ sudo sntp -sS pool.ntp.org 
-9.789671 +/- 0.018845 pool.ntp.org 95.81.173.74
```

Which does not show date and time, but also no major offset.

The offset is consistent at 5 months, 2 days, 3 hours and 10 minutes.

- Tried `time.apple.com` and `pool.ntp.org`. No luck.
- Tried different time zones. No luck.
- Tried VPN to fake a different physical location. No luck.
- Changed WiFi networks, including using my phone as hotspot. No luck.
- NVRAM reset didn't help. No luck.

[image: Manually set correct date and time]

[image: Date and time set automatically —> Wrong, today is 30/9/2020]

**Fix**

It somehow got fixed when I installed `sntp` (part of the `ntp` package) via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) and ran it after running

```
sudo touch /var/db/ntp-kod
sudo chown root:wheel /var/db/ntp-kod
```

Note: I don't know if the installation of `sntp` via Homebrew is needed as macOS also has its own version.

Comment: I was hoping to try this, but Homebrew now gives this error when I try to install sntp: "Warning: No available formula with the name "sntp". Did you mean sntop, stp, ntp, snap or srtp?"

Comment: It's part of `ntp`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm experiencing similar issues, though the offset is different from yours (6 months something). Using `sudo sntp -sS pool.ntp.org` (with built-in `sntp`) does update the date and time to the correct one. However, if I switch "automatically sync date and time" off and on again, it's back to the same wrong date and time. Did your solution (using `sntp` from homebrew) also solve this issue?

Comment: Yes, I used `sntp` from `homebrew`. As notec I also had to create some files. I think I had the checkmark set when I ran the command. But it's 3+ years ago..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excellent question. There is a lot that you can do to inspect this process.

- [How can I tell if my Mac is keeping the clock updated properly?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117864/how-can-i-tell-if-my-mac-is-keeping-the-clock-updated-properly)

Some things to point out:

- Check which time servers you have selected
- Change them and retest
- If you have a VPN, try that and be sure you try without
- Look over your time zone (set it if it’s not correct while you sort out the time servers

Some computer is telling yours the wrong time, so think about networks and then dig into the command line tools if needed.

Comment: Thanks @bmike. I added some information to my original question.

Comment: Awesome! Just making the tracking file seems a bit silly we have to do that in some cases... @Volsk - well done.

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered a similar issue, where the automatic time sync leads to months of time difference.

Tried the "solution" the OP mentioned, but it only worked for tens of minutes and was gone to the wrong one.

Later I found a solution for me from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/17oznvu/automatic_date_and_time_is_wrong/). The highest-rated comment proposes

```
sudo rm /var/db/timed/com.apple.timed.plist
```

followed by a reboot (!).