# Date is wrong by months when set to automatic on 12.1 Monterey (MacBook Pro 14)

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, monterey, time

Upon booting up by machine (2021 MacBook Pro 14 on 12.1) after fully running out of battery for the first time (I've owned the machine for a couple months) I noticed the date and time were completely wrong by a number of months. The offset is consistent and displays today's date as 25th September 2021, it is currently the 8th of January 2022.

[image: date and time preference pane]

I've tried resetting the SMC, restarted the machine a few times, have checked all date and time settings as normal and appropriate - unchanged from when I first set it up.

```
alex@Alexs-MacBook-Pro ~ % ntpdate -q pool.ntp.org
server 188.125.64.7, stratum 2, offset +9088877.936268, delay 0.07085
server 162.159.200.1, stratum 3, offset +9088877.930845, delay 0.05722
server 162.159.200.123, stratum 3, offset +9088877.932137, delay 0.05659
server 85.91.1.180, stratum 2, offset +9088877.938617, delay 0.05498
25 Sep 06:35:35 ntpdate[1630]: step time server 85.91.1.180 offset +9088877.938617 sec
```

Running the following command resyncs the date and time perfectly, but after about a day when left in automatic mode or by unchecking and rechecking the box it resets back to the massive offset.

```
sudo sntp -sS time.apple.com
```

I noticed a user with a similar problem in the forum but was unable to use any solutions provided:

[Date is wrong by months when set to automatically](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/402427/date-is-wrong-by-months-when-set-to-automatically)

Comment: Try switching it to manual, set it somewhere close to correct, reboot & try auto again.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately the issue persists.

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of the Date & Time Preference pane, with the server set automatically?

Comment: @benwiggy added one to the post.

Comment: I have seen de-selecting automatic time zone as a solution.

Comment: @benwiggy Thanks, I gave that a try but no change unfortunately. It just seems like something is bugged somewhere - I'm not sure how the process works but it's like it's resetting to an old time before syncing and then failing on the sync.

Comment: Try using a different time server.

Comment: Did you disable the Location Services for some reason? I once noticed that my Mac can't sync date and time properly any more if the Location Services are disabled.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same issue and solved it as follows:

- the process responsible for the system clock is "timed"
- the man page says it stores its configs in /etc/ntp.conf and /var/db/timed/com.apple.timed.plist

I manually deleted both files and restarted my mac. You need root to delete the files. Now sntp to time.apple.com shows an offset of 2secs, but that seems to be a known bug.

Comment: Thanks, so much! This was the only answer I found that worked.

Comment: Can you word this in English for computer dummies as I don't know anything sntp etc????

Comment: @Subseauk A year later but for others: it means to run `sudo rm /etc/ntp.conf` and `sudo rm /var/db/timed/com.apple.timed.plist`.

Comment: @user3932000 I tried this, restarted, but still have the same issue