# Why is my (automatic) clock running 8 minutes behind?

Tags: macos, time, clock

I just realized my macbook's clock is 8 minutes behind. And yet the setting is on "automatically set to date and time". See screenshot. How can I fix this?

On the left: asking for "time" in google. 14:32
On the right: 14:24 and the "automatic" box is ticked

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your Automatic time update is set to wrong link.

You have no set up for Automatic Time Update !

What is Twitter doing there anyhow?

[image]

Use this and set to Europe or whatever Continent you are. [image]

Comment: You have to be a little off to use Twitter.

Comment: @WGroleau funny !

Comment: hahaha!!!  good one!

Comment: lol I didn't even pay attention to that

Answer (score 1):

This might help.

[How can I tell if my Mac is keeping the clock updated properly?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117864/how-can-i-tell-if-my-mac-is-keeping-the-clock-updated-properly)
And, this
[ntpd: consistently incorrect time on mid-2013 MacBook Air](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/111834/ntpd-consistently-incorrect-time-on-mid-2013-macbook-air)

TL;DR:  open a command prompt, aka Shell, aka "Terminal".

What's the output of 'ntpq -p'?
What is in /var/db/ntp.drift ?

A list of servers is available at http://support.ntp.org/servers; you have to try to select the servers that are close to you, especially not just geographically, but network-wise.

Comment: Thanks for those commands. So ntpq -p said "server unavailable" and drift had -64.893.
server unavailable makes sense (see answer below...) for me.
In what unit is the 'drift'?

Comment: Server unavailable means that it can't find the time server, and thus your clock is not actually automatic.  Don't worry about the drift, when it connects it can automatically correct for that.  Worry that you can't connect to the time server.  Try a different time server.